# ColorDialog1 delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. При работе с компонентам ColorDialog1 возникла такая загвоздка при исполнении вот этого кода

```
var
  s:string;
  p1,p2:Integer;
begin
  S:=formMain.RichEdit1.Text;
  p1:=formMain.RichEdit1.SelStart;
  p2:=p1+formMain.RichEdit1.SelLength;
  if ColorDialog1.Execute=true then
  S:=Copy(S,1,p1)+'<span style="color:' + ColorToString(ColorDialog1.Color) + '">'+Copy(S,p1+1,p2-p1)+'</span>'+Copy(S,p2,Length(S));  
formMain.RichEdit1.Text:=S;
```

в Richedit  выводится цвет какой выбрал **но** он выводится либо вот так $0040FF00 либо **cl**Aqua от чего это зависит и как сделато что бы выводился просто цвет без приски **cl**

Answer (score 2):

все правильно выводит. в Дельфи формат цвета такой - $00000000. Константы вида clAuqa лишь задают цвету понятное значение. ColorToString переводит значение цвета (конст. или общий формат) в строку.
вам, насколько я понял, нужен цвет в RGB. используйте функции: GetRValue(TColor), GetGValue(TColor), GetBValue(TColor).

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит только от того что вы юзаете `ColorToString(ColorDialog1.Color)`
а для вашей задачи нужно юзать  `FmtStr(s, '%s%0.8x', [HexDisplayPrefix, Integer(clREd)]);`
в ColorToString есть внутренний список имен цветов функция ColorToString сначала их проверяет а потом уже (если не нашла) пытается преобразовать цвет к дефолтному формату $00000000(как адрес) поэтому напишите свою функцию и все.

```
function ColorToStr(Color:TColor):string;
begin
  FmtStr(Result, '%s%0.8x', [HexDisplayPrefix, Integer(Color)]);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно!
Вы присвоили *RichEdit1.Text* значение цвета и Вам показывается его адрес или название.

Как я понял по коду  - Вы именно это и хотите! Пргосто удалить первые 2 буквы и будет Вам счастье. 
Length в помощь.